# Calculating integral with exponential function and parameter

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to calculate this integral but Mathematica does not solve it.
Why? Can it be solved by Mathematica?

```
Integrate[Exp[-(Sqrt[1 + x^2] - 1)/t]*x^2, {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

I asked Mathematica to change variables to

```
 "u == Sqrt[1 + x^2] - 1"
```

and the result is Bessel function.
but I'm not sure if

```
"IntegrateChangeVariables"
```

works properly.

This is the result:

ConditionalExpression[Exp^(1/t) t BesselK[2, 1/t], Re[t] > 0]

Comment: Perhaps you have a typo...   t-->x?

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci no, it's t

Comment: Haha so this is a little awkward, I did exactly what you did for the add-on edit to your post in your question, and posted it at the exact same time you made the edit. I did some numerical confirmation of the result for explicit values of $t$ at the bottom of my answer though to confirm `ConditionalExpression[Exp^(1/t) t BesselK[2, 1/t], Re[t] > 0]` is in fact equal to the integral

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 8):

You just need to change variables. Using $u=\sqrt{x^2+1}$ appears to work:

```
int = Exp[-(Sqrt[1 + x^2] - 1)/t]*x^2;

new = IntegrateChangeVariables[
  Inactive[Integrate][int, {x, 0, Infinity}], u, u == Sqrt[1 + x^2]]

(*Inactive[Integrate][
 E^((1 - u)/t) u Sqrt[-1 + u^2], {u, 1, \[Infinity]}]*)
```

Yields $$\int _1^{\infty }u \sqrt{u^2-1} e^{\frac{1-u}{t}}du$$

Activating the output:

```
Activate[new]
(*ConditionalExpression[E^(1/t) t BesselK[2, 1/t], Re[t] > 0]*)
```

So $$\int_0^{\infty } x^2 \exp \left(-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-1}{t}\right) \, dx = e^{1/t} ~t~ K_2\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$$

for $\Re(t)>0$, where $K_n(t)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Looking experimentally with values of $t$, we see this is correct

````
Table[NIntegrate[int, {x, 0, Infinity}], {t, 5}]
(*{4.41677, 24.8963, 73.3853, 161.878, 302.373}*)

Table[(E^(1/t) t BesselK[2, 1/t]), {t, 5}] // N

(*{4.41677, 24.8963, 73.3853, 161.878, 302.373}*)

```
````